# Remove artifacts from CI manually

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a private repository at gitlab.com that uses the CI feature. Some of the CI jobs create artifacts files that are stored. I just implemented that the artifacts are deleted automatically after one day by adding this to the CI configuration:

```
expire_in: 1 day
```

That works great - however, old artifacts won't be deleted (as expected). So my question is:

How can I delete old artifacts or artifacts that do not expire? (on gitlab.com, no direct access to the server)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [GitLab REST API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#erase-a-job) to delete the artifacts from the jobs if you don't have direct access to the server. Here's a [sample curl script](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2018/01/remove-gitlab-ci-artifacts-in-batch.html) that uses the API:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
# project_id, find it here: https://gitlab.com/[organization name]/[repository name]/edit inside the "General project settings" tab
project_id="3034900"
    
# token, find it here: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
token="Lifg_azxDyRp8eyNFRfg"
server="gitlab.com"
    
# go to https://gitlab.com/[organization name]/[repository name]/-/jobs
# then open JavaScript console
# copy/paste => copy(_.uniq($('.ci-status').map((x, e) => /([0-9]+)/.exec(e.href)).toArray()).join(' '))
# press enter, and then copy the result here :
# repeat for every page you want
job_ids=(48875658 48874137 48873496 48872419)
    
for job_id in ${job_ids[@]}
do
     URL="https://$server/api/v4/projects/$project_id/jobs/$job_id/erase"
     echo "$URL"
     curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${token}" "$URL"
     echo "\n"
done
```

Comment: This console command worked for me: `copy([...$('a[title="Download artifacts"],a[download]').map((x, e) => /\/([0-9]+)\//.exec(e.href)[1])].join(' '))`.

Comment: This also deletes the job log according to the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#erase-a-job). Since GitLab 11.9 there is a separate [API endpoint for deleting only the artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#delete-artifacts), maybe you would like to update your answer?

Comment: Note that this will delete the jobs along with the artifacts. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551589/7370354) for a way to keep the jobs and delete only the artifacts.

Comment: The provided js commandline script does not work.

Answer (score 28):

An API call should be easier to script, with [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#bulk-delete-artifacts-with-the-api) (January 2022), which now offers:

> ### Bulk delete artifacts with the API
>
> While a good strategy for managing storage consumption is to set regular expiration policies for artifacts, sometimes you need to reduce items in storage right away.
>
> Previously, you might have used a script to automate the tedious task of deleting artifacts one by one with API calls, but now you can use a new API endpoint to bulk delete job artifacts quickly and easily.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#delete-project-artifacts), [Issue 223793](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223793) and [Merge Request 75488](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/75488).

```
 curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
      "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/artifacts"
```

---

As noted by [Lubo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11152683/lubo) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512733/remove-artifacts-from-ci-manually/70817349?noredirect=1#comment135314243_70817349):

> Response of given API is [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202). It means for me, that deletion will happen on background.
>
> Also admin area ís updated a bit later than deletion happens

Comment: Out of curiosity will this delete the raw job logs associated with each job as well? Do those count towards the artifact storage limit?

Comment: @BrianJordan Apparently, it does *not* delete logs: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223793#note_443460706. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/75488 mentions "erasable job artifacts - all job artifacts except trace".

Comment: I get '202: Accepted' back but the Artifacts size of my repository remains the same.

Comment: @GrogPirate With what version of GitLab? Or is it gitlab.com? In any case, it is best to ask a separate question.

Comment: @GrogPirate We have the same problem on gitlab.com, this bulk delete api seems not work, or does not what is expected.

Comment: @nadar I unfortunately ended up moving the repository since I could not get rid of the remaining artifacts.

Comment: Response of given API is 202 Accepted. It means for me, that deletion will happen on background. Also admin area ís updated a bit later than deletion happens.

Comment: @Lubo Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The same request with the gitlab library in Python:
```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('YOUR URL', private_token='YOUR TOKEN')
project = gl.projects.get('YOUR PROJECT ID')
project.artifacts.delete()
```

Answer (score 16):

Building on top of @David 's answer,
@Philipp pointed out that there is now an api endpoint to delete only the job artifacts instead of the entire job.

You can run this script directly in the browser's Dev Tools console, or use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to run in node.js.

```js
//Go to: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
const API_KEY = "API_KEY";

//You can find project id inside the "General project settings" tab
const PROJECT_ID = 12345678;
const PROJECT_URL = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/" + PROJECT_ID + "/"

let jobs = [];
for(let i = 0, currentJobs = []; i == 0 || currentJobs.length > 0; i++){
    currentJobs = await sendApiRequest(
        PROJECT_URL + "jobs/?per_page=100&page=" + (i + 1)
    ).then(e => e.json());
    jobs = jobs.concat(currentJobs);
}

//skip jobs without artifacts
jobs = jobs.filter(e => e.artifacts);

//keep the latest build.
jobs.shift();

for(let job of jobs)
    await sendApiRequest(
        PROJECT_URL + "jobs/" + job.id + "/artifacts",
        {method: "DELETE"}
    );

async function sendApiRequest(url, options = {}){
    if(!options.headers)
        options.headers = {};
    options.headers["PRIVATE-TOKEN"] = API_KEY;

    return fetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to use yours above in Chrome console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at <anonymous>:28:44
    at async <anonymous>:21
(anonymous) @ VM62:28

Comment: @Stanford I fixed the script, can you try again?

Answer (score 11):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#erasing-artifacts), deleting the entire job log (click on the trash can) will also delete the artifacts.

Answer (score 4):

I am on GitLab 8.17 and am able to remove artifacts for particular job by navigating to storage directory on server itself, default path is:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/<year_month>/<project_id?>/<jobid>
```

Removing both whole folder for job or simply contents, disappears artifact view from GitLab pipline page.

The storage path can be changed as described in docs:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/administration/job_artifacts.md#storing-job-artifacts

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no direct access to the server as the repository is hosted at gitlab.com. I updated my question to point that out in more detail.

Comment: According to GitLab, you'll want to delete through the gitlab-rails console if you have access to the GitLab server itself. Otherwise, you may see discrepencies when looking at project size in the admin UI because the underlying database isn't updated. Ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/5572#note_3359570

Answer (score 2):

If you have deleted all the jobs by accident (thinking the artifacts would be gone, but they didn't) what would be the alternative then brute-forcing a loop range?

I have this code, which does bruteforce on a range of numbers. But since I use the gitlab.com public runners, It's a long-range

```
    # project_id, find it here: https://gitlab.com/[organization name]/[repository name]/edit inside the "General project settings" tab
project_id="xxxxxx" #

# token, find it here: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
token="yyyyy"
server="gitlab.com"


# Get a range of the oldest known job and the lastet known one, then bruteforce. Used in the case when you deleted pipelines and can't retrive Job Ids.

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609966/for-loop-over-sequence-of-large-numbers-in-bash
for (( job_id = 59216999; job_id <= 190239535; job_id++ )) do
echo "$job_id"

echo Job ID being deleted is "$job_id"

curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${token}" "https://${server}/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/jobs/${job_id}/erase"
echo -en '\n'
echo -en '\n'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This Python solution worked for me with GitLab 13.11.3.

```
#!/bin/python3
# delete_artifacts.py  

import json
import requests

# adapt accordingly
base_url='https://gitlab.example.com'
project_id='1234'
access_token='123412341234'

#
# Get Version Tested with Version 13.11.3
# cf. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/version.html#version-api
#
print(f'GET /version')
x= (requests.get(f"{base_url}/api/v4/version", headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": access_token }))
print(x)
data=json.loads(x.text)
print(f'Using GitLab version {data["version"]}. Tested with 13.11.3')

#
# List project jobs
# cf. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-project-jobs
#
request_str=f'projects/{project_id}/jobs'
url=f'{base_url}/api/v4/{request_str}'
print(f'GET /{request_str}')
x= (requests.get(url, headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": access_token }))
print(x)
data=json.loads(x.text)

input('WARNING: This will delete all artifacts. Job logs will remain be available. Press Enter to continue...' )

#
# Delete job artifacts
# cf. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#delete-artifacts
#
for entry in data:
    request_str=f'projects/{project_id}/jobs/{entry["id"]}/artifacts'
    url=f'{base_url}/api/v4/{request_str}'
    print(f'DELETE /{request_str}')
    x = requests.delete(url, headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": access_token })
    print(x)
```

I'll keep an updated version [here](https://gitlab.com/fabiangabel/gitlab_cleanup). Feel free to reach out and improve the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind removing entire jobs along with their artifacts in bulk, you can use the [`glab`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/) CLI like this:

```
glab ci delete --dry-run --older-than 8760h --paginate
```

This removes all jobs older than 1 year.  Just remove `--dry-run` to make it happen.

The artifacts seem to be deleted asynchronously, so it may take some time for your repository's storage usage to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's possible to change the retention time by adding a [artifacts:expire_in](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsexpire_in) field in the job settings.

In my testing in Gitlab 15.10.2-ee, the setting is applied retroactively to all matching jobs in the history. The deletion is not instant: it presumably happens once some scheduled job runs, probably once a day.

You could also change the [instance-wide setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/continuous_integration.html#default-artifacts-expiration) but that doesn't apply to past artifacts.

Comment: There is the parameter [`expire_build_artifacts_worker_cron`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html#expiring-artifacts) in `gitlab.rb`.