# Why is my artifact storage so high? How can I get rid of it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to get my namespace storage <5GB, but I have one project that is using up almost all of the space because it's artifact storage is 4.5GB.

[Screenshot of my usage quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPIdF.png)

We have pipelines set to run every push to GitLab, but the pipelines are quite simple: install necessary packages and run tests.  The only artifacts we explicitly save are log files (usually only a few KB, if anything), and screenshots of failed browser tests (again, a couple of MB at most).  We also have artifacts set to expire after 24 hours.

We have a small team, so even on our busiest day, we won't have more than 15 pipelines run, and if each pipeline saves 5MB (way more than reality), it should be 75MB a day -- which should expire down to 0 MB after 24 hours.

I recently unchecked "Keep artifacts from most recent successful jobs" in **Settings > Usage Quotas > CI/CD > Artifacts** but it had been checked for a year or so (since we started the project).

Other steps I've tried is making API calls to [delete all artifacts in the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#delete-project-artifacts) and I wrote a script to [get all job IDs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-project-jobs) and [delete all artifacts for each job ID](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#delete-job-artifacts).

Is it possible that we have GB of old successful job artifacts clogging up our storage?  Is it possible to browse & delete artifacts manually?

Edit: this is using Gitlab.com, not self-hosted.

Comment: If your job traces are very large, that's another possible source of artifact storage. Though, it would probably take quite some time to accumulate a GB+ in job logs alone. You could try deleting the old jobs/pipelines altogether. Are you using self-hosted gitlab or gitlab.com?

Comment: GitLab.com. How would I go about deleting old jobs/pipelines.

Comment: If on gitlab.com, you may have to wait some time for the artifact calculation to update. You can use the [delete pipeline API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#delete-a-pipeline) to delete pieplines. Deleting a pipeline will delete "all immediately related objects, such as builds, logs, artifacts, and triggers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per sytech's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733270/why-is-my-artifact-storage-so-high-how-can-i-get-rid-of-it/73820571#comment130228107_73733270), I wrote a PHP script to get all pipeline IDs and delete any pipelines that are older than 1 week.  This removed around 3000 old pipelines, and my storage quota went from from ~5GB to ~150MB.  Here's the script in case anyone is interested:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Keep all pipelines 7 days and newer
 */
$cutoffTime = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);

$ids = [];
$page = 1;

/**
 * Get list of all pipeline IDs and store old IDs in array
 */
do {
    $response = `curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <API_KEY>' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/pipelines?page=$page&per_page=100' -s`;
    $pipelines = json_decode($response);
    foreach ($pipelines as $pipeline) {
        if (strtotime($pipeline->updated_at) < $cutoffTime) {
            $ids[] = $pipeline->id;
        }
    }
    $page++;
} while ($pipelines);

/**
 * Delete all pipelines in IDs array
 */
$count = 0;
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo "Deleting $id ($pipeline->updated_at): ";
    $response = `curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <API_KEY>' --request 'DELETE' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/pipelines/$id' -s`;
    if (!$response) {
        echo "Done\n";
        $count++;
    } else {
        echo json_decode($response)->message . "\n";
    }
}

/**
 * Print results
 */
if ($ids) {
    echo "\nDeleted $count pipelines.\n\nDone.\n";
} else {
    echo "\nNo pipelines found older than 1 week\n\nDone.\n";
}
```